# nrfutil changes python version mid-script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm using nrfutil in a shell script. It's failing with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/nrfutil", line 6, in <module>
    from nordicsemi.__main__ import cli
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nordicsemi/__main__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from nordicsemi.zigbee.prod_config import ProductionConfig, ProductionConfigWrongException, ProductionConfigTooLargeException
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nordicsemi/zigbee/prod_config.py", line 41, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 374
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
```

It's starting in python 2.7, then it looks like its running "import yaml" from a 3.6 library.
Why would it do this? How do I prevent it?
Thanks

Comment: I would think that you should be running python 3 at this point. If you are still running 2.7 I would-suggest a fresh python 3 install.

Answer (score -1):

I had an old version of nrfutil. I upgraded, all is good